Is it possible to convert a neural network saved as a checkpoint to h5 format?
There is a trained neural network (Object Detection Model) that is saved as a Checkpoint, that is, there are 4 files:

labels.pbtxt
ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001
ckpt-1.index
pipeline.config

Is it possible to convert and save this neural network in Keras *.h5 format?
P.S. I can restore the specified model,like this:
 PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR = "/content/saved_model"
 PATH_TO_CFG = PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR + "/pipeline.config"
 PATH_TO_CKPT = PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR + "/checkpoint"

where dir "checkpoint" include:

labels.pbtxt
ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001
ckpt-1.index

we pre-install the Object Detection API and then
Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs =     config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_CFG)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

Restore checkpoint
 ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
 ckpt.restore(os.path.join(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'ckpt-1')).expect_partial()
 tf.saved_model.save(ckpt, export_dir='/content/model')

but I can't save it later as model.save()==>
ckpt.save('myModel.h5', save_format='h5')

I get: "TypeError:Checkpoint.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_format'",
but I can save as:
 tf.saved_model.save(ckpt, path_to_saved_dir)

is it possible to somehow convert the model into a single *.h5 file after that?

Does this answer your question? How to convert a checkpoint to a Keras .h5 model?

Unfortunately, in the link (answer) to the question you specified, we are talking about something else. You can download some pre-trained model (for example: !wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/efficientdet_d2_coco17_tpu-32.tar.gz ) and see in what format it is saved.
These will be 4 files, just as I indicated above.
I don't need to teach her anymore.
The question is, how can I convert it (so that I can save it later) this model is in the *.h5 format (save the entire model).

see: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/serialization_and_saving
Simply put, how can I get a model from these four files so that I can save it as:
model = ...  # Get model (Sequential, Functional Model, or Model subclass)
model.save('path/to/model')
